# .svg Icons in Android bad quality

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, svg, icons

I am painting a series of icons based on an XML from an .svg.

The first load the icon looks perfect but when an new activity is invoked and destroy then to return to where the icon is, it loses all the quality of its lines, seeing these as "bites."

I think the problem would come since the views containing the icons are not being repainted.

How could I solve this? Any other possible implementation? Could you get .png images without losing quality?

Comment: Did you try `view.invalidate()` Generally, invalidate() means 'redraw on screen'

Comment: @dustblue I just tried it. Same result. Thanks for your proposal.

Comment: Are you able to provide some code?

Comment: @Tom Sorry but the code is too extend to post it. The painting is: `image.setImageResource (getImageResource (getData (). GetCategories (). Get (0) .getId (), image.getContext ()));` after it I execute image.invalidate();

Comment: try reloading the picture in `onActivityResult`